# How do I use a variable within a range for graph plotting?

Tags: excel, graph, vba

I want to loop plotting graph by using this code:

```
1  For i = 354 To 357

2    Range((Cells(208, 353)), Cells(219, 353)).Select
3    Range(Cells(208, i), Cells(219, i)).Select

4    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
5    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
6   ' ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet2!Cells(208,354):Cells(219,354)")
7    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
8    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
9    ActiveChart.ApplyLayout (9)

10    Next i
11 End Sub
```

However, there is a runtime error in line 6, could anyone help please?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the problem line you need to set correct reference to sheet and range of cells. Therefore that line of code should look like:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(208,354),Cells(219,354))
```

Comment: Thanks KazJaw! Greatly appreciate this, I spent many unfruitful hours before this. Works just fine!